# Qt GUI input validation with XML schema types

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, xsd, validation

We are working on a cross-platform that should offer a Qt GUI to write to XML files. There will be a set of configurable XML element/attributes that will be modifiable in a Qt GUI using QLineEdit and so on.

How can we add input validation that conforms to the types defined in the XML schema? The types are all `simpleType` like:

```
<xs:element name="age">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="100"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Short of reimplementing input validation for all xml schema types, are there other feasible approaches. I had the idea of creating XML Schema and XML documents for the currently visible input fields and their input, validate it using [QXmlSchema](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qxmlschema.html) and then display the validation error message. However that seems overly complex and might be slow.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/xmlpatterns-schema.html) is a good example of XML schema validator. In the example the schema is validated with a QPushButton, but you could do that once the editing is finished for example, or text changed.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a short summary of the content of this article? I know it will close to impossible to come up with an explanation as thorough as the one provided by Qt, but I think that SO aims at being as much self-contained as possible (i.e. with few dependencies to outside sources).

Comment: Well in the article the XML input is validated against predefined schemas that are loaded from the disk. As I understand you have multiple schemas to be validated against. So using this approach you can just iterate through them. This will get ugly though if you have a very large number of them.

Comment: @Neox: I've seen the example application too, but it's essentially the same as my idea to create the XML document and the schema on the fly and then validate. I have a variable user-configurable number of fields based on `simpleType` like age that I need to validate. Instead of validating everything, I'd like to find a way to validate each field individually to be able to give instant feedback to the user.